# How to join multiple tables in MongoDB like SQL JOIN

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

### mailbox

mailbox:{
_id:"2",
title:"test"
}

### mailbox_details

mailbox_details:{
_id:"1",
mailbox_id:2,
is_read : false
}

These are the tables.

I have attached the image of code please check.
[image]

-Unfortunately I did not get the result I expected

Below is the output I intended

### output

{
title:"test",
mailbox_id:2,
is_read : false
}.

Once I get this, I can take the next step. please help me.

Comment: You need to check your $match object. you are matching true. This will not fulfill your result. You can use $project to filter the response

Comment: Thanks @harpreetcheema .I have already tried this. But I did not get the result I expected.



db.collection("mailbox_details").aggregate([
{
$lookup: {
localField: "mailbox_id",
from: "mailboxes",
foreignField: "_id",
as: "mailinfo"
}
}, { $match : { "mailinfo.is_read" : true } },

{ $unwind: "$mailinfo" },
{ $project: {
"is_read": 1,
"mailbox_id": 1,
"mailinfo.title": 1,
} }
]).toArray((err: any, result: any) => {
if (err) { throw err; }
console.log("result", result);
});

Comment: please help me. very urgent

Answer (score 1):

Try with this. I am using mailbox_details as a parent collection.

```
db.collection("mailboxes").aggregate([
  { $match : {
      "is_read": true
    }
  },
  { $lookup: { localField: "_id", from: "mailbox_details", foreignField: "mailbox_id", as: "mailinfo"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$mailinfo"
  },
  { $project: {
      "is_read": 1,
      "mailbox_id": 1,
      "mailinfo.title": 1,
    }
  }
]).toArray((err: any, result: any) => { if (err) { throw err;
  } console.log("result", result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @HermenpreetSingh. Let me try and see if it works

Comment: Hi @HermenpreetSingh . This is the output of this code.
result [].
Not Working

Comment: @ArunDas Please share your collection data , I will try on my local.